# Heroku throwing error when loading css template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bootstrap-4

I'm building a Rails 5 app that uses Bootstrap 4 and a template.  Everything works fine locally, but when I try to push to heroku, the template doesn't load and I get these errors in the logs:

```
2020-03-05T15:26:26.781532+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2020-03-05T15:26:26.781403 #4]  INFO -- : [394c9216-8bc2-4aff-a779-117853a42dd7] Started GET "/assets/template.css" for 24.126.131.137 at 2020-03-05 15:26:26 +0000
2020-03-05T15:26:26.782417+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-03-05T15:26:26.782335 #4] FATAL -- : [394c9216-8bc2-4aff-a779-117853a42dd7]
2020-03-05T15:26:26.782593+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-03-05T15:26:26.782525 #4] FATAL -- : [394c9216-8bc2-4aff-a779-117853a42dd7] ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/template.css"):
2020-03-05T15:26:26.782685+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-03-05T15:26:26.782620 #4] FATAL -- : [394c9216-8bc2-4aff-a779-117853a42dd7]
2020-03-05T15:26:26.782798+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2020-03-05T15:26:26.782731 #4] FATAL -- : [394c9216-8bc2-4aff-a779-117853a42dd7] vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/actionpack-5.2.4.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:65:in `call'
```

I've googled all of them and can't seem to figure out the source of the errors. I've included all code below that I believe is relevant.  I'm new to rails and heroku, so if any other files are required for trouble shooting, let me know.

application.scss:

```
 // Custom bootstrap variables must be set or imported *before* bootstrap.
@import "bootstrap";
@import "template.css";
@import "tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css";
```

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= csp_meta_tag %>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/854fb36a23.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= yield %>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are your assets compiling on deploy to Heroku - Do you see the lines: Preparing Rails asset pipeline
       Running: rake assets:precompile

Comment: Yes.  Everything seems to be compiling fine.  I can't tell which files specifically are compiling because their names seem to be hashed.  Any other ideas?  I'm really at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.  I removed .css from the @import of template.css and tempusdominus-bootstrap-4.css.  It's working now.